# match.arg behaviour not coherent

Tags: r, radix

I find this behavior very confusing:

```
choose_language <- function(language = c("R", "python", "C")) {   
   language <- match.arg(language, several.ok = FALSE)   
   paste('I love', language)  
}
```

`choose_language(language = "R")`

> "I love R"

`choose_language(language = c("R", "python"))`

> Error in ...  OK

`choose_language(language = c("R", "python", "C"))`

> **"I love R"**

Why this happen?

I would expect the same behavior as the following function:

```
choose_language <- function(language = "R") {
checkmate::assertChoice(language, choices = c("R", "python", "C"))
  paste('I love', language)  
}
```

but without `checkmate` dependency

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of `match.arg()` within the `choose_language()` function is correct, but it is the one-argument form of `match.arg()`.  Check the documentation specifically for this:

*"In the one-argument form match.arg(arg), the choices are obtained from a default setting for the formal argument arg of the function from which match.arg was called. (Since default argument matching will set arg to choices, this is allowed as an exception to the ‘length one unless several.ok is TRUE’ rule, and returns the first element.)"*

If you update your function to explicitly include the `choices` argument, like this

```
choose_language <- function(language = c("R", "python", "C")) {   
  language <- match.arg(arg=language, choices = language, several.ok = FALSE)   
  paste('I love', language)  
}
```

then you will find that all of your above examples return `"I love R"`
`

Comment: Thank you @langtang, ... but now is even more confusing as `choose_language("xxxxx")` will return `"I love xxxxx"`.    Is not suppose to through  an error?

Comment: you are correct.. It would be beter to explicitly set the choices as `choices=c("python", "R", "C")`, but then you need to recognize the fact that matching is done using `pmatch`, and the role that several.ok plays. Also note that even if several.ok is FALSE, if what is passed fully matches the choices, it will take the first one

Comment: The problem now with `choices = c("R", "python", "C")`, is that don't work for `choose_language(language = c("R", "python"))`, or if I put the arguments in different order. It has to be, only one argument or all the arguments in the same order. Anyway, Thank you very much @langtang

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't work". It correctly returns an error indicating that length has to 1 because several.ok is FALSE, (or it has to be all the arguments; see the documentation)

Comment: I mean that I don't understand the logic that `choose_language(c("R", "python", "C"))` return `"I love R"` and `choose_language(c("python", "C", "R"))` return and error. I will keep using `checkmate`, which behavior is much more clear for me.  Thank you for your effort

Comment: When `several.ok=FALSE`, `arg` must be length 1 *unless it exactly matches choices*.. I agree with you that perhaps this exception is not alway intuitive.